# Find a repeated words in a column cell value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Sample Data:

```
Col A                           Col B
Grand Theft Auto Grand Theft    Grand,Theft
```

```
Sub Repeatwrd()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cellValueA As String
    Dim cellValueB As String
    Dim wordsA As Variant
    Dim wordsB As Variant
    Dim wordIndex As Long
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim wordCount As Integer

    
    
    ' Get the last row of data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row of data in column A and compare with column B
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Get the values in columns A and B for the current row
        cellValueA = Cells(i, 1).Value
        cellValueB = Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        ' Split the strings into words
        wordsA = Split(cellValueA, " ")
        wordsB = Split(cellValueB, " ")
        
        ' Loop through each word in column A
        For wordIndex = 0 To UBound(wordsA)
            ' If the word is not found in column B, highlight it in column A
            If InStr(cellValueB, wordsA(wordIndex)) = 0 Then
                word = wordsA(wordIndex)
                ' Highlight the word in column A
                Cells(i, 1).Characters(InStr(cellValueA, word), Len(word)).Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' Highlight in red
                'Add highlight word in c column
                'Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & " " & word

            End If
        Next wordIndex
        
        
         ' Loop through each word in the string
        For Each word In wordsA
            ' Count the number of occurrences of the word in the string
            wordCount = UBound(Split(cellValueA, word)) - LBound(Split(cellValueA, word))
            
            ' If the word occurs more than once, paste it in column C for the current row
            If wordCount > 1 Then
                'ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = word
                 Cells(i, 3).Value = word
                Exit For ' Exit the loop once a repeated word is found
            End If
            ' If the word occurs more than once, paste it in column C for the current row
            If wordCount > 1 Then
                'ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = word
                 Cells(i, 3).Value = word
                Exit For ' Exit the loop once a repeated word is found
            End If
        Next word
 Next i
End Sub
```

i can get one value Grand how get both repeated words( Grand,Theft) values in col b?

Comment: Can you explain the specific problem you're having?

Comment: You shoul add data example and expected output

Comment: data sample: Grand Theft Theft  Expected result : Theft the repeat word need to be identified

Comment: should be ```wordCount > 1``` , not  > 0

Comment: You haven't answered what the current problem is, what's going wrong?

Comment: for example data: Grand Theft Auto Grand Theft 
how to identify both repeat words 

Excepted result: Grand,Theft

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a dictionary, collection or array to record what you have found and processed for subsequent disposal, rather than leaving the loop immediately.

```vb
Sub Repeatwrd()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cellValueA As String
    Dim cellValueB As String
    Dim wordsA As Variant
    Dim wordsB As Variant
    Dim wordIndex As Long
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim wordCount As Integer
    
    ' Get the last row of data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row of data in column A and compare with column B
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Get the values in columns A and B for the current row
        cellValueA = Cells(i, 1).Value
        cellValueB = Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        ' Split the strings into words
        wordsA = Split(cellValueA, " ")
        wordsB = Split(cellValueB, " ")
        
        ' Loop through each word in column A
        For wordIndex = 0 To UBound(wordsA)
            ' If the word is not found in column B, highlight it in column A
            If InStr(cellValueB, wordsA(wordIndex)) = 0 Then
                word = wordsA(wordIndex)
                ' Highlight the word in column A
                Cells(i, 1).Characters(InStr(cellValueA, word), Len(word)).Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' Highlight in red
                'Add highlight word in c column
                'Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & " " & word
    
            End If
        Next wordIndex
        
        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        
         ' Loop through each word in the string
        For Each word In wordsA
            ' Count the number of occurrences of the word in the string
            wordCount = UBound(Split(cellValueA, word)) - LBound(Split(cellValueA, word))
            ' If the word occurs more than once, paste it in column C for the current row
            If wordCount > 1 Then
                If Not dict.exists(word) Then
                    'ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = word
    '                 Cells(i, 3).Value = word
                     Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & " " & word
                     dict.Add word, word
'                    Exit For ' Exit the loop once a repeated word is found
                End If
            End If
            ' If the word occurs more than once, paste it in column C for the current row
'            If wordCount > 1 Then
'                'ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = word
'                 Cells(i, 3).Value = word
'                Exit For ' Exit the loop once a repeated word is found
'            End If
        Next word
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get repeated value in target col : trick is to remove the all occurence of tested word in original cell at each loop.

Replace second part of your example code with what follows below :

```
'temp string for concat results
Dim sResult As String
'temp string for deduplication
Dim sHaystack As String
sHaystack = cellValueA 

For Each word In wordsA
    'erase test word in original string
    sTmp = Replace(sHaytack,word,"")

    'if length reduction is bigger than tested word...
    If (Len(sHaystack) - Len(sTmp)) > Len(word) Then
      'means the word occurs more than once, so saving it
      'concatenating previous result if any
      If sResult <> "" Then
        sResult = ", " & word
      Else
        sResult = word
      End If
    Else
      'if no length reduction or equal to word, do nothing
    End If

  'next loop with a testword-stripped string
  sHaystack = sTmp

Next word
'now paste concatenated result in column C
Cells(i, 3).Value = sResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and UDF in VBA to check this, considering a word anything between 2 blanks, or at start of string with trailink blank or end of string with leading blank. Sum all of those cases. If the sum is greater than 0,it's a dupplicate.

[image]

This UDF needs 2 arguments: `rng1` would be words to check and `rng2` would be the range containing the duplicates of `rng1`. Notice the output sorting is different depending on how you set up `rng1` and `rng2` but the words are the same:

```
Public Function GET_DUP_WORDS(ByVal rng1 As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range) As String
Dim wordArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim test As Long
Dim targetWord As String
wordArray = Split(rng1, " ")

For i = LBound(wordArray) To UBound(wordArray)
    'word is something between 2 blanks
    'or at the end of string with a leading blank
    'or at start of string with a trailing blank
    
    targetWord = wordArray(i)
    
    test = Evaluate(Replace("=SUM(COUNTIF(" & rng2.Address & ",{""* targetWord *"",""targetWord *"",""* targetWord""}))", "targetWord", targetWord))
    
    If test > 0 Then GET_DUP_WORDS = GET_DUP_WORDS & targetWord & ", "
Next i

'get rid of last comma in case there is something
If Len(GET_DUP_WORDS) > 0 Then GET_DUP_WORDS = Left(GET_DUP_WORDS, Len(GET_DUP_WORDS) - 2)

End Function
```

Formula in column C is: `=GET_DUP_WORDS(A1;B1)`
Formula in column D is the opposite: `=GET_DUP_WORDS(B1;A1)`

You can combine this UDF inside a SUB to apply for a full range.